# Will using python for rendering speed up the process?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, video

I have a very basic setup for blender. I have wrapped a video around a sphere as material, and positioned the camera at its center. I now plan to move the camera around. The camera is set to the equirectangular mode.

When I render using the GUI, it takes about 4 minutes per frame to render. Can this time be reduced if I proceed to do this using a python script? If so, is there a significant difference?

Comment: Assume you mean  [rendering in background mode](http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/advanced/command_line.html#render-options)  Where `blender -b file.blend -f 1` renders frame 1 in background mode.  No python necessary, might get some time improvement with no GUI.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for the prompt response. I actually didn't ave any specific rendering mode in mind. I just want to reduce the rendering time, and therefore asked whether using python would speed up the rendering process or not.

Comment: If you want to speed up render times, consider "How to speed up render times" as a question,.  Is rendering in bg mode quicker for your blend?